# Change line height of data coming in from JSON url in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

Hi I have an app that brings in data from a JSON url, I am trying to change the line height of some of the typography namely the `articleContentValue`, previous answers on here use a String as a value but mine is using an article structure. So far my code is the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class myVC: UIViewController {

    var article: Article?

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var articleTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var articleContentValue: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let article = article {

            articleTitle.text = article.name
            mainImageView.hnk_setImage(from: article.mainImage)
            articleContentValue.text = article.content

        }

        articleContentValue.textColor = UIColor(red:0.27, green:0.27, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0)

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: any issue faced here ?

Comment: I have changed the colour for articleContentValue as you can see, but how do I change the line height? that is the question?

Comment: line height means label height ? can you elaborate this ?

Comment: The spacing between lines of text...

Comment: can i suggest third party library for maintain line of height ?

Comment: That's unclear. Line height in the text of a single label, or space between different labels according to the content they have? "previous answers on here use a String as a value but mine is using an article structure" What article structure? From what I see `articleContentValue.text = article.content`: `article.content` is a String.

Comment: @Larne what do you suggest as a solution then..

Comment: @Sole A solution? Explain more your issue, show some screenshot maybe, for me, you issue is still unclear, I asked "Line height in the text of a single label, or space between different labels according to the content they have", because that's TWO different issues, TWO different management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: article.content)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2 // Whatever line spacing you want in points
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    articleContentValue.attributedText = attributedString;
```